# Reorganise svn folder structure Tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, trunk

I have an SVN repository named 'Solution' (contains many projects) created without the default trunk, branch etc structure. I'd like to move this to the recommended structure.

I have created the new folder structure on the server where 'Team' is the root containing aforementioned trunk and branches. So should I relocate locally to Team/Trunk or copy locally and Add to the new repo folders? I'd like to maintain history in the process, if possible.

I have read a number of SO posts on this theme, but it seems there are many ways of getting this right or wrong, depending on circumstances.

Also, I'm new to SVN and development in general, hence I need GUI instructions as opposed to command line, please, sorry to be non-developer about it. Doing my best.

Illustration:

```
(Existing)
    Solution/
            Project folders/

(Proposed)
    Team/
            Trunk/
                 /Project folders
            Branches/
```

Comment: What is "Team"? is it a new repository or it created child of "Solution"

Comment: Thanks Olive. Team is a new repository - currently empty. Should I create the new structure within 'solution' and move all project folders into that

Comment: Why did you create another repository? You don't mind losing the commit history in the previous repo (though, there are ways to transfer the history over to the new one - not recommended)? I would create the new structure in the current repo and `svn move` the project folders into that, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need to create an entirely new repo in order to reorganize your projects.

Secondly, if you can, checkout the entirety of your **Solution** repo somewhere, and create and `svn add` the **branches, tags, trunk** folders. Do NOT commit them yet; you will `svn move` every other folder (the project folders) into **trunk** and then commit everything in one go.

To illustrate, I created a **SampleRepo**, checked it out, then `svn add`ed and `svn commit`ted a few placeholder project folders:

[image: Initial repo folder structure]

Then, I created the **branches**, **tags**, and **trunk** folders at the root of the repo checkout, then `svn add`ed them using TortoiseSVN:

[image: SVN Add Option in TortoiseSVN]

The repo checkout now looks like this:

[image: The repo checkout after adding the branches tags trunk folders]

Now, I select all of the project folders, and right-drag them over to the **trunk** folder, selecting **SVN Move versioned item(s) here**:

[image: TortoiseSVN's svn move option]

The root of the **SampleRepo** folder now contains just the **branches**, **tags**, and **trunk** folders. If you right-click any whitespace in the **SampleRepo** folder, and select **TortoiseSVN** `->` **SVN Check for modifications**, you should see something like this:

[image: The status of the repo checkout after the svn move]

Finally, I right-click any whitespace in the **SampleRepo** folder, and choose **TortoiseSVN** `->` **SVN Commit...**, add a commit message, and click **OK**.

Now, if I right-click any whitespace in the **SampleRepo** folder -> **TortoiseSVN** `->` **SVN Show log** I will see this:

[image: The log of the repo]

All done!

NB: The reason I asked for a complete checkout of the repo is because then you can minimize the number of commits you'd have to make in order to achieve the restructuring you want. You *can* perform the restructure server-side using TortoiseSVN's Repo Browser, but then you'd need to commit every folder move, one at a time.

More reading:

- [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)
- TortoiseSVN's Help File, usually found here: `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN_en.chm`

Comment: Sameer singh that's a clear answer and well explained, thank you.

Comment: @Rufyan Glad to help! :) Please remember to mark this as the answer once you're done with your restructure and don't require any further help.

Comment: Thanks. After doing that, I had to do a **TortoiseSNV -> Switch...** to the new /trunk/ folder on the original projects.

Comment: @kannas I'm glad this helped!

Comment: @J.A.Cado I added pictures when I first answered the question. Do you not see them?